# Use of Canvas App In AppExchange

Tags: integration, appexchange, canvas-app

We have a requirement for an AppExchange app where we would like to embed the pages build within external website (composite app) in to Salesforce.

As per various article, Canvas App supports embedding 3rd party pages within Salesforce and it also provides authentication mechanism like signed request or oAuth2.
We understand any app being embedded within Salesforce should be security compliant and entire 3rd party application will go through security review. The 3rd party site which we are planning to embed is security compliant.

In this scenario, is there any disadvantage of using Canvas app within AppExchange?

If canvas app can't be used we have other options as below:

- SSO implementation and instead of embedding 3rd party within Salesforce, redirect user to a 3rd party website
- Implement the custom UI like 3rd party app in Salesforce and use API (3rd party website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas Apps can be used in an AppExchange package, and the other options could work as well. You can use whichever one you would find easiest to implement.